# SIGTERM is not captured by sigwait()

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, unix

I'm writing a program that replys on SIGTERM/SIGINT to terminate. This is a multi-thread program. Basically I have a dedicated thread that is waiting for SIGTERM and SIGINT by calling sigwait and I will notify the main thread upon receving the signals in this thread.
I sent the SIGTERM signal to this program by executing command "killall nameofprocess". However, I found that it will work as expcted only in 10%. Most of times I have to run the "killall" command twice to terminate this program. I'm wondering why the sigwait doesn't capture the SIGTERM the first time. (Same case for SIGINT when I run kill -2)
Is it possible that the signal is received by some other threads?

```
static std::atomic<bool> shutdown_requested(false);
static std::mutex cv_mutex;
static std::condition_variable cv;
int main()
{
  sigset_t sigset;
  sigemptyset(&sigset);
  sigaddset(&sigset, SIGINT);
  sigaddset(&sigset, SIGTERM);
  pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, nullptr);

  ....do something including creating some threads.....

  //a dedicated thread that waits for signals
  auto signal_handler = [&sigset]() {
    int signum = 0;
    // wait until a signal is delivered:
    sigwait(&sigset, &signum);
    shutdown_requested.store(true);
    // notify all waiting workers to check their predicate:
    cv.notify_all();
    return signum;
  };

  auto signal_handler_async = std::async(std::launch::async, signal_handler);

  //wait for cv
  while(shutdown_requested.load() == false)
  {
    std::unique_lock lock(cv_mutex);
    cv.wait(lock, [](){return shutdown_requested.load();});
  }

  ..........clean up and exit..............
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you make this into a [mcve]?  POSIX [says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) that a signal shall be delivered to some thread which is either in `sigwait` or has the signal unblocked.  So if all your other threads really had it blocked, the `sigwait`ing thread should indeed get it.  So either the kernel is broken (unlikely) or your program isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: Try using sigwaitinfo in place of sigwait.

Comment: @kjohri, I replaced sigwait with sigwaitinfo and dump the siginfo_t. In the case when sigwaitinfo returns -1, info.si_signo, info.si_code and info.si_errno are all 0.